# Schools in psychology

Tags: study-cognitive-sciences

Where I can read a good overview on schools/trends in psychology (behaviorism, gestalt, freudism etc)?
And which of them is most scientific/evidentiary and less "art"

Comment: A textbook/introductory book on psychology?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Psychology.SE.

As @Ooker was indicating, a question asking for a "good" overview on different sections of psychology is going to generate a very opinion-based answer and because of the nature of such questions, they do not fit well with StackExchange sites due to the way they work.

The question on which is most scientific is also opinion-based as there are areas of psychology [considered by some here to be pseudoscientific](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2242) by some and not by others.

I would look at reading introductory books on psychology.  In my view, any by Routledge  or SAGE publications would give a fairly thorough rundown on the different theory bases etc.

For free ebooks you won't go far wrong reading the [ones available from the International Psychotherapy Institute](https://www.freepsychotherapybooks.org/) (although I am not affiliated  to them). Being who they are, the institute's selection will have a strong leaning towards Freudian and Neo-Freudian psychology but they will give you a start.